# Align columns at decimal point using siunitx wherein each cell contains superscripted table-notes

Tags: tables, siunitx, threeparttable, dcolumn, tablenotes

I am using the `threeparttable` package to typeset a table with some footnotes.

I would like to align the entries in each numerical column using the facilities provided by `siunitx`.  However, when table entries have the footnotes label, it messes up the column alignment.

[image: Table issue with SIunitx alignment]

In the first numerical column with *leading* tnote labels, the alignment does not happen. In the 2nd numerical column with *trailing* tnote labels, the alignment works fine, but the tnote superscript labels do not stay close to the number.

What I need is the *leading* tnote version wherein the column is aligned at the decimal point, and the superscripted labels stay close (perhaps with a `\thinspace` at best) to each number in the column.

How can this be achieved? I am happy to use `dcolumn` or `pgftables` package if necessary, instead of `siunitx`.

Here is the code to produce the above table

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{The best table ever}
    \label{tbl:importanttable}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=4.2] S[table-format=4.2]}  % Works with tnote
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{@{} l}{Description} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Experiment 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Experiment 2} \\
            \midrule

            First thing,  & \tnote{a} 1791 & 2427 \tnote{b} \\
            Second thing & \tnote{a} 272.8 & 90.2 \tnote{c} \\
            third thing & \tnote{d} 82.28 & 43.72 \tnote{d}\\
            Fourth thing & \tnote{d} 3 & 130 \tnote{e}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        \item[a] blah
        \item[b] more blah
        \item[c] stuff
        \item[d] assumed
        \item[e] given
        \end{tablenotes}

    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

#### Update

Using the `makebox*{00}[l]\tnote{a}` technique from the answer by user Bernard required hand-tuning of the textwidths, which is problematic for anything larger than a handful of cells. For instance, this does not work for the table below.

```
    Thing1  & {\tnote{a}}0.31   \\
    Thing2  & {\tnote{b}}2.40   \\
    Thing3  & {\tnote{d}}6.50   \\
    Thing4  & {\tnote{c}}6.00   \\
    Thing5  & {\tnote{e}}8.94   \\
    Thing6  & {\tnote{f}}26.82  \\
    Thing7  & {\tnote{e}}13.41  \\
    Thing8  & {\tnote{f}}1.20   \\
    Thing9  & {\tnote{g}}0.75   \\
    Thing10 & {\tnote{c}}150.60 \\
    Thing11 & {\tnote{f}}0.01   \\
    Thing12 & {\tnote{g}}0.00   \\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'tell' `siunitx` that commands are not to be expanded: that's easiest done using `etoolbox` and it's `\robustify` command. Then you need to reserve a bit of space, using `table-space-text-pre` (this will be simplified in upcoming v3 of the package). For `\tnote`, there is an additional wrinkle as the definition does some spacing stuff of it's own, which confuses the approach in `siunitx`. We therefore need a modified command here too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\Tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript {\TPTtagStyle {#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{The best table ever}
    \label{tbl:importanttable}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=4.2,table-space-text-pre=\Tnote{a},table-align-text-pre=false] S[table-format=4.2]}  % Works with tnote
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{@{} l}{Description} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Experiment 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Experiment 2} \\
            \midrule

            First thing,  & \Tnote{a} 1791 & 2427 \Tnote{b} \\
            Second thing & \Tnote{a} 272.8 & 90.2 \Tnote{c} \\
            third thing & \Tnote{d} 82.28 & 43.72 \Tnote{d}\\
            Fourth thing & \Tnote{d} 3 & 130 \Tnote{e}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        \item[a] blah
        \item[b] more blah
        \item[c] stuff
        \item[d] assumed
        \item[e] given
        \end{tablenotes}

    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this does not work at all.

Comment: Okay, with `table-align-text-pre = false` flag in the middle column, this works fine and answers the original question. Curiously, although it works with the latest Siunitx version as of today (v 2.7s), in the version that shipped with TL2017, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: with `\robustify\tnote` option `table-align-text-pre=false` doesn't work (siunitx, v2.7s, last revised 2018/05/17). `note` is not aligned to numbers.

Comment: @Zarko Well, it works for me. I am on `v2.7s` as well. Please double check if an older installation of TL is not earlier in your `PATH`. I am saying so because this answer is confirmed to be __not working__ in TL2017.

Comment: @Krishna, i used recent MikTeX and have recent `siunitx` available in MikTeX. i can compile, but result is the same if the option  `table-align-text-pre=false` is present or not or if it is set to `true`.

Comment: @Krishna It's an issue specifically with `\tnote`: the general approach is working. I've modified the answer to deal with that.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for providing the update. This does not solve the issue completely. It causes weird spacing issues, for example in a cell if you have `\Tnote{m} 1150.0`, the `m` crashes into `1` in a horrible manner. Please try it out. I am using Libertinus 12 pt font.

Comment: @Krishna Well yes, because `m` is wider than `a`, which I've used in the model. You have to tell `siunitx` the maximum width of the pre-text: it can't guess that, unfortunately (Would require a two-pass approach).

Comment: @JosephWright thank you. That makes sense. I reckon that typesetting `tablenotes` is a common enough case. With `3.0` of `siunitx`, would you consider providing "out-of-the-box" compatbility with `siunitx`. I mean, detect if `threeparttable` is loaded, and apply the `robustfy` macro to `tnote` or something? I mean, this could benefit a large number of users (after all typesetting aligned numbers and having explanatory table notes for some of the numbers should be common, right?)

Comment: @JosephWright And I fail to understand why the robustified version of `tnote` has different behavior in `miktex` and `texlive`? It worked for me, but failed for user Zarko.  That's simply weird.

Comment: @JosephWright  I think that the spacing between the leading `tnote` and the numerical entity in the cell should not be held to a fixed width of an apriori set length. In fact, for good typesetting, I think that after the `tnote` glyph (whatever it may be) and before the first  numercal, a predetermined amount of space must be used.

Comment: @Krishna Then add one to your command: I can't predict that in `siunitx`

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a problem with the alignment of pre-table notes (maybe a bug?), but I can solve the problem for table notes *after* the numbers. This is the best I could obtain, adding the `caption` package for a better spacing between caption and table, and simplifying the code for the first row (no `\multicolumn` required):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper ,top=3cm, bottom=2cm, hmargin=3cm, marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{The best table ever}
    \label{tbl:importanttable}
    \centering
\sisetup{table-format=4.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-pre=\textsuperscript{a}, table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{a}, table-align-text-post=false}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} l SS} % Works with tnote
            \toprule
            Description & {Experiment 1} &{Experiment 2} \\
            \midrule
            First thing, & {\tnote{a}} 1791 & 2427 \tnote{b} \\
            Second thing & {\tnote{a}} 272.8 & 90.2 \tnote{c} \\
            third thing & {\tnote{d}} 82.28 & 43.72 \tnote{d}\\
            Fourth thing & {\tnote{d}} 3 & 130 \tnote{e}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        \item[a] blah
        \item[b] more blah
        \item[c] stuff
        \item[d] assumed
        \item[e] given
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

Here is a hack with the small `makebox` package to have the table notes in the 2nd column close to the numbers:

```
\usepackage{makebox}
....................
   \begin{table}[htb]
        \caption{The best table ever}
        \label{tbl:importanttable}
        \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=4.2, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-pre=a, table-align-text-pre=false, table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{a}, table-align-text-post=false}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{@{} l SS} % Works with tnote\textsuperscript{a}
                \toprule
                Description & {Experiment 1} &{Experiment 2} \\
                \midrule
                First thing, & {\tnote{a}} 1791 & 2427 \tnote{b} \\
                Second thing & {\makebox*{0}[l]{\tnote{a}}} 272.8 & 90.2 \tnote{c} \\
                third thing & {\makebox*{0}[l]{\tnote{d}}} 82.28 & 43.72 \tnote{d} \\
                Fourth thing & {\makebox*{0}[l]{\tnote{d}}} 3 & 130 \tnote{e} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            \item[a] blah
            \item[b] more blah
            \item[c] stuff
            \item[d] assumed
            \item[e] given
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was really hoping to get some traction with the leading table-notes, rather than the trailing ones. It looks like `table-space-text-pre=\textsuperscript{a}` is not working, right?

Comment: It works, what's not working is `table-align-text-pre=false` (I tried it, but as it didn't work, I didn't use it in the code I posted). Maybe there's an interaction with the `S` column type.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Maybe is there a possibility to use `dcolumn` package for this, or (shudder) the `pgftables` package?

Comment: Maybe. I haven't been using `dcolumn`  for many years.

Comment: @Krishna: I've found a hack for the second column, with package `makebox`. However, I don't know why it works…

Comment: that's awesome. Thank you very much. Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: Sorry, this does not seem to be generic enough. The width of the `makebox` macro needs  to be hand-tuned to get the spacing correct, and if we have a complex table with more rows and columns with a wider spread in the number of places before the decimal point, then it takes quite a bit more effort. I would like to have something more robust. Unaccepting the answer for now.

Comment: @Krishna: That's what  I thought first, and I began coding `\makebox*{0}` in the second row, `\makebox*{00}` in the third and `\makebox*{000}` in the fourth. It didn't change whatever, so I concluded that, for some reason, the main point was to have a `\makebox` of a non-zero width. Could you post an example code where this doesn't work?

Comment: That is exactly what I had to do. `makebox*{000}` and sometimes even things like `makebox*{10}` because the width occupied by `0` and `1` glyphs are different. I shall try posting my example where this strategy fails

Comment: Anyway, I looks very much like a bug  in siunitx. One shouldn't have to hack to solve the problem. Maybe you should write the author about it.

Comment: Joseph is not currently seen in chat. It's the weekend after all. I have posted a bug report in github. You may wish to add your thoughts to the issue. https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/350

Comment: see Joseph's answer below. It looks to me as if there was a bug that got fixed in the updates sometime over the last one year.  (TL2017 did not work)